# Django & Ajax: How can I create a csv file download from posting data through AJAX to Django?

Tags: python, ajax, django, csv, download

I'm trying to allow the click trigger to do some backend dynamic csv creation, and then return it back to the user as a csv download file. I guess I'm not sure how I should write out the return statement other than just putting `return response`. I'v come across some other posts saying that I would need to set my url to a hidden iframe?? Not sure what this means though. Any tips?
Ajax looks like this:

```
       $('#download-maxes').on('click', function(){
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "{{request.path}}download/",
                dataType: 'json',
                async: false,
                data: JSON.stringify(workouts),
                success: function(workoutData) {                        
                    console.log(workoutData);
                },
                error:function(error){
                    console.log(error);
                }
            });
        });
```

And my django view looks like this:

```
def download(request):
    #(... a lot of mongo stuff here & other things defined)
    workouts = json.load(request.body)
    response = HttpResponse(content_type='text/xlsx')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="team_maxes.xlsx"'
    writer = csv.writer(response)
    writer.writerow(['Name', 'Date', 'Workout', 'Max'])

    for member in team_members.all():
        for wo in workouts:
            wo_data = db.activity_types.find_one({"name": wo["name"]})
            best_wo = db.activity.find_one({"u_id": member.user.id, "a_t": str(wo_data["_id"]), "is_last": 1}) or 0

            member_name = member.user.first_name + ' ' + member.user.last_name

            try:
                max_stat = best_wo["y_ts"]
            except:
                max_stat = 0

            try:
                date = best_wo["e_d"]
            except:
                date = ""

            workout_name = wo_data["name"]

            writer.writerow([member_name, date, workout_name, max_stat])

    return response
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to use ajax. Since you are `POST`ing some json data to your view, just make a form with a hidden text input, and set it's value to the json data. Then make a regular submit button in the form.

When the form gets submitted, and the server responds with `Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="team_maxes.xlsx"`, your browser will automatically trigger a download.

If you decide to go this route, Keep in mind:

- You are using a regular html form now, with the `POST` method, so you must remember to use django's `{% csrf_token %}` tag inside of it.
- You will probably have set the input's value to your json string, right before submitting the form.
- Your `workouts` json gets sent in a form input. So, assuming you named your input "workouts", in your view you would do something like:

  ```
  workouts = json.loads(request.POST.get('workouts'))
  ```

  Plus a bunch of error checking, of course.